# How to parse GTFS data on iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, parsing, gtfs

I am using http://datamine.mta.info/list-of-feeds api to get GTFS data for United States transportation.

When you call `http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=<key>&feed_id=1` api you get one "gtfs" file which contains data that I need to parse in iOS so that I can display.

Once I get the file, how do I parse it? So far I haven't found a way to do so. Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Is it just coma-separated-values what you're having troubles parsing?

Comment: When I downloaded the file using my key the gtfs file is not readable so I don't know what exactly is there in that file.

Comment: If you're interested in the real-time GTFS feeds, then it's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). You should really read the docs, it's all there.

Comment: Ok thanks let me check Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The MTA requires that you serve the realtime data from your own server, so you might as well parse the Protocol Buffers server-side, and then make your data available to your iOS app from your server. If you do it that way, then you can use e.g., a Python or C++ library to parse the PB into JSON or whatever and structure it in an optimal way for your app for download.

Comment: Currently I am following the same approach where PHP team is trying to parse that GTFS file on back end and once they do they will provide the data, but I think there should be a easy way to handle this parsing on iOS side too.

Comment: Yeah sure I will, currently looking into Protocol Buffers.